# vim displays content of file with @-signs

Tags: windows, file, powershell, vim, encoding

I used vim to open a file `event.txt` and show me some search results. This worked fine, but since I did a change in the `_vimrc` it displays the file content with `@`-signs so that it is unreadable. See image below. 
[image: event.txt with @-signs] 
What I did change in `_vimrc` was

```
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

but I commented it. So it should not affect vim.

```
"set fileencoding=utf-8
```

The file is still displayed unreadable. With other editors I can open the file and view it normally. I had this behaviour some time ago, but I vanished somehow. I can't remember.

The `event.txt` file is the windows event file which I generate through the powershell:

```
get-eventlog -logname system > event.txt
```

Something tells me it's not the change in the `_vimrc` and perhaps something else, but this is the last change I remeber I did and after this it did not work.

How can I view in vim the windows event file `event.txt` normaly? Without `@`-signs.

Comment: [try this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `ÿþ` at the beginning is a *byte order mark* (BOM), typical for Windows *Unicode* text. The `^@` is Vim's representation of a NUL value, and it (roughly) appears as every second character. So, you have a (mostly) ASCII-text file, encoded in UCS-2 little endian: each character is represented by two bytes (16 bit), the lower one comes first.

You can open that file with

```
:edit ++enc=ucs2-le event.txt
```

But it's better to set up Vim correctly so that it automatically detects it. Since you're using GVIM on Windows, I would recommend to put

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

at the start of your `~/.vimrc`. This will automatically set your `'fileencodings'` to a good default of `ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`. Note the first element; that should help detect the file.

**Do not set `'fileencoding'` in your `~/.vimrc`!** That is a *buffer-local* setting, and it will be automatically set by Vim on opening of the file. The `'fileencodings'` (note the plural) is the right option to influence the detection.

Comment: ``:set encoding=utf-8`` worked perfect. Thanks. As well for the detailed explanation.